# Setting a Maximum and Minimum Amplitude in Sine graph

Tags: graphing-functions

I currently have a translated sine graph with the following formula:

$$\left(\sin\left(\frac{x}{50 / \pi} - \frac{\pi}{2}\right) + 1\right) \cdot 0.5$$

Which makes a graph like this

[image]

However I need to have the amplitude range between $0.2$ and $1.0$. Is there any way I can do this, while keeping the mentioned range as a variable, such as changing the min and max range at will?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy to construct, $\sin$ goes from $-1$ to $+1$ so you just shift and stretch:
$$f(x)=\text{min}+\frac12(\text{max}-\text{min})(1+\sin (kx+\phi))$$
or, if you prefer
$$f(x)=\text{average} + \text{amplitude}\cdot \sin (kx+\phi)$$
where average=(max+min)/2 and amplitude = (max-min)/2.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, I'm coming from a software development angle into a math world, I have no idea what `(kx+ϕ)` means, or what variables they translate to.

Comment: You already have that, I just used a generic expression for horizontal stretch and phase shift. In your case, $kx+\phi=\pi x/50-\pi/2$. I thought you'd pick that up by comparison to your expression. Use whatever symbols you like, it could have been ž for all we care...

Comment: Unless I'm doing this wrong - using a max of `1` and a min of `0.2`, the plotted graph from the first equation ranges from `0` to `1.2`, instead of `0.2` to `1`

Comment: You probably forgot the $1+$ in the parentheses. You can see what I did... $\sin$ is in the interval $[-1,1]$. So first I add $+1$ to make it $[0,2]$. Then I cut it in half to squeeze it in the range $[0,1]$. Then I multiply with the span between max and min to make it just wide enough, $[0,max-min]$. Finally, I shift it up by $min$ to push it into range $[min,max]$ which is what you wanted.